# #include errors for navigation package

Tags: navigation, ros-noetic, include, dwa-local-planner

sorry if this is dumb I'm new to cpp and ros, but am currently using this: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation

but I keep getting the error across basically every file I open:
#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. (/home/widogast/catkin_ws/src/navigation/dwa_local_planner/src/dwa_planner.cpp).
cannot open source file "dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerConfig.h" (dependency of "dwa_local_planner/dwa_planner.h")

what I've done so far is open c_cpp_properties.json and manually added the folder to the path by identifying where it is and adding to "includePath":
"/home/widogast/catkin_ws/src/navigation/dwa_local_planner/include/**"
I've tried a couple of variations on the address but nothing seems to work.
any advice is welcome, thanks :)

here's my current c_cpp_properties.json file
'''

{
"configurations": [
{

```
        "includePath": [
            "/home/widogast/catkin_ws/devel/include/**",
            "/opt/ros/noetic/include/**",
            "/home/widogast/catkin_ws/src/navigation/**",
            "/usr/include/**",
            "\\wsl.localhost\\Ubuntu-20.04\\home\\widogast\\catkin_ws\\src\\navigation\\dwa_local_planner\\include\\dwa_local_planner\\"
        ],
        "name": "ROS",
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        "cStandard": "c17",
        "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
        "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4
```

}
'''
and Ive tried multiple other pathways incase it needed to be of a certain format. heres a look at the overall file placement as well. Any help is incredibly appreciated as Ive explored about every option I could find. Ive tried with it ending in \** as well for the path file.
[image]